# Obtaining database objects and converting / editing them for the view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dao

I am developing a web application using Spring.
I am using a database to store user profiles. For the sake of simplicity I have 3 java files: userDAO.java, userController.java and userType.java

As its apparent from file names the controller processes the URL calls, it fetches a user profile object by providing the user id to a method stored in userDAO.java.

My question is what is the best approach for modifying certain user object properties (userType) before they are sent to the view. This is when the request is being processed by the controller.

Should I create a new userType (ex. UserTypeforView) and map the original userType to userTypeforView and include my modifications.
Example:

```
...   
UserTypeforView usertypeforview = new UserTypeForView();

if (usertype.getType() == 1)
   usertypeforview.setMembership("Free membership");
else if(usertype.getType() == 2)
   usertypeforview.setMembership("Premium membership");  
...
```

or Should I make the userType very loosely typed and flexible so that I can easily change its property types, or add new properties? I think this approach would be difficult because it would cause problem with mapping db objects with userType.

Is there any other way? Is there a way to create an object on the spot inside the controller ? Or should I perform the conversation in the views and not controller?

Note I'm using Spring MVC 3 as well.

Comment: Please give an example for 'modifying certain user object properties'! What would be the difference between `userType` and a possible `userTypeforView`? Also I'm not sure what you think of, when saying 'create an object on the spot inside the controller'. I suppose it doesn't mean sth like `SomeClassName scn = new SomeClassName()`, does it?

Comment: @MyBrainHurts  thank you, I updated the question with sample code.

Comment: Thanks picolo - now I get it. I think it's very common to have objects just for the view. So, `UserTypeforView` might be a solution. Maybe it matches your needs to inherit from `UserType` and just adding a property `membership`. It might a well be an apt thing to do to just have one object containing all the data you need in the view. That depends a lot on your application. But I would absolutely not hard code the membership descriptions. For many reasons it's better to read them from the database. Make a detail table, another query and leave the task of mapping to the database.